# Erro ao criar gráfico com dados de API - Axios/Vue

Tags: vue.js, chartjs, axios

Olá, estou construindo um gráfico que coleta dados meteorológicos da cidade de Curitiba através de um retrieve de uma API, porém nada é coletado e assim o gráfico não é criado, estou utilizando de vue/axios para este sistema.

Gostaria de uma luz nesse problema.

Código Axios:

```
  var app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
      chart: null,
      dates: [],
      probability: [],
      precipitation: [],
      loading: false,
      errored: false
    },
    methods: {

        if (this.chart != null) {
          this.chart.destroy();
        }

        axios
          .get("http://apiadvisor.climatempo.com.br/api/v1/forecast/locale/6731/days/15?token=5ffc1cd67c7deb0d259d9388ea9db118")
        .then(response => {
          this.dates = response.data.list.map(list => {
            return data.date_br;
          });

          this.probability = response.data.list.map(list => {
            return data.rain.probability;
          });

          this.precipitation = response.data.list.map(list => {
            return data.rain.precipitation; }
          });


          /* Gera o gráfico */
      var ctx = document.getElementById("barChart");
          if (ctx) {
            ctx.height = 200;
            var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
              type: 'bar',
              defaultFontFamily: 'Poppins',
              data: {
                labels: this.dates,
                datasets: [
                  {
                    label: "Chuva (%)",
                    fill: false,
                    data: this.probability,
                    borderColor: "rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.9)",
                    borderWidth: "0",
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.5)",
                    fontFamily: "Poppins"
                  },

                  {
                    label: "Precipitação (mm)",
                    fill: false,
                    data: this.precipitation,
                    borderColor: "rgba(240,248,255)",
                    borderWidth: "0",
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(0,255,255)",
                    fontFamily: "Poppins"

                  }
                ]
              },
              options: {
                legend: {
                  position: 'top',
                  labels: {
                    fontFamily: 'Poppins'
                  }

                },
                scales: {
                  xAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                      fontFamily: "Poppins"

                    }
                  }],
                  yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                      beginAtZero: true,
                      fontFamily: "Poppins"
                    }
                  }]
                }
              }
            });
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            this.errored = true;
          })
          .finally(() => (this.loading = false));
      }
    }
  });
```

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
        <div class="my-5">
          <div class="alert alert-info" v-show="loading">
            Loading...
          </div>
          <div v-show="chart != null">
            <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</html>
```

Obrigado.

Comment: Já reparaste que tens dois pontos aqui `response..data`? Que erro te dá o código?

Comment: Esse método `getData` é chamado onde?

Comment: @Sergio Nossa, não tinha visto esses pontos e em relação ao erro, não da erro nenhum, só não exibe nada.

O getData é um método abandonado, esqueci de retirar do código, porém era para ser usado caso fosse feito um sistema de busca por cidade, coisa que não precisa ser feita, peço desculpas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu código deveria estar dentro do método mount do VueJs, assim ele irá executar a execução do ajax, no momento em que ele montar todo o componente. Esse é o código que está funcionando, recomendo você estudar o ciclo de vida do vue e melhorar algumas coisas que estão ruins nessa solução. Bons estudos!

```
 var app = new Vue({
el: "#app",
data: {
  chart: null,
  dates: [],
  probability: [],
  precipitation: [],
  loading: false,
  errored: false
},
mounted () {

    if (this.chart != null) {
      this.chart.destroy();
    }

    axios
      .get("http://apiadvisor.climatempo.com.br/api/v1/forecast/locale/6731/days/15?token=5ffc1cd67c7deb0d259d9388ea9db118")
    .then(response => {
      this.dates = response.data.list.map(list => {
        return data.date_br;
      });

      this.probability = response.data.list.map(list => {
        return data.rain.probability;
      });

      this.precipitation = response.data.list.map(list => {
        return data.rain.precipitation; }
      });


      /* Gera o gráfico */
  var ctx = document.getElementById("barChart");
      if (ctx) {
        ctx.height = 200;
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
          type: 'bar',
          defaultFontFamily: 'Poppins',
          data: {
            labels: this.dates,
            datasets: [
              {
                label: "Chuva (%)",
                fill: false,
                data: this.probability,
                borderColor: "rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.9)",
                borderWidth: "0",
                backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.5)",
                fontFamily: "Poppins"
              },

              {
                label: "Precipitação (mm)",
                fill: false,
                data: this.precipitation,
                borderColor: "rgba(240,248,255)",
                borderWidth: "0",
                backgroundColor: "rgba(0,255,255)",
                fontFamily: "Poppins"

              }
            ]
          },
          options: {
            legend: {
              position: 'top',
              labels: {
                fontFamily: 'Poppins'
              }

            },
            scales: {
              xAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                  fontFamily: "Poppins"

                }
              }],
              yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                  beginAtZero: true,
                  fontFamily: "Poppins"
                }
              }]
            }
          }
        });
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        this.errored = true;
      })
      .finally(() => (this.loading = false));
  }
}
 });
```

Segue o código funcionando, notei que o nome da div estava errada e você não estava pegando o contexto do canvas, troquei também o v-show por v-if, a diferença entre eles é que o v-show só esconde o elemento e o v-if cria ou destói o mesmo.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="my-5">
      <div class="alert alert-info" v-if="loading">
        Loading...
      </div>
      <div v-if="!loading">
        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
      dates: [],
      probability: [],
      precipitation: [],
      loading: false,
      errored: false
    },
    mounted() {

      axios
        .get(
          "http://apiadvisor.climatempo.com.br/api/v1/forecast/locale/6731/days/15?token=5ffc1cd67c7deb0d259d9388ea9db118"
        )
        .then(response => {
          const infograph = response.data.data
          this.dates = infograph.map(list => {
            return list.date_br;
          });

          this.probability = infograph.map(list => {
            return list.rain.probability;
          });

          this.precipitation = infograph.map(list => {
            return list.rain.precipitation;
          });


          /* Gera o gráfico */

          var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');;
          if (ctx) {
            var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
              type: 'bar',
              defaultFontFamily: 'Poppins',
              data: {
                labels: this.dates,
                datasets: [{
                    label: "Chuva (%)",
                    fill: false,
                    data: this.probability,
                    borderColor: "rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.9)",
                    borderWidth: "0",
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.5)",
                    fontFamily: "Poppins"
                  },

                  {
                    label: "Precipitação (mm)",
                    fill: false,
                    data: this.precipitation,
                    borderColor: "rgba(240,248,255)",
                    borderWidth: "0",
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(0,255,255)",
                    fontFamily: "Poppins"

                  }
                ]
              },
              options: {
                legend: {
                  position: 'top',
                  labels: {
                    fontFamily: 'Poppins'
                  }

                },
                scales: {
                  xAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                      fontFamily: "Poppins"

                    }
                  }],
                  yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                      beginAtZero: true,
                      fontFamily: "Poppins"
                    }
                  }]
                }
              }
            })
          }
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
          this.errored = true;
        })
        .finally(() => (this.loading = false));
    }
  })
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Apesar de realmente precisar da mounted, o erro ainda persiste.

Comment: Dei uma olhada e resolvi debbugar, encontrei uma série de erros, vou editar o post para lhe mostrar a solução

Comment: Sempre que que eu fico horas no mesmo código acontece essas besteiras kk. Obrigado pelo ajuda, mano!